# How to filter by key in an enumerable of dictionaries?

Tags: c#, dictionary, ienumerable

I have an enumerable collection of dictionary which contains some duplicate values. i want to remove those duplicate values, here is my data where ID is duplicated but with a different CompanyID

[image]

I tried this code to filter data, but still it returns the same.

```
  foreach (int rowval in rowscol)
                    {    
                        Dictionary<string, object> Data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        foreach (Contracts.CommonDataField field in finalColumns)
                        {
                            string value = record.CommonDataValues.SingleOrDefault(row => row.RowID == rowval && row.FieldName == field.FieldName).RecordFieldData.ToString();
                            Data.Add(field.FieldName, value);
                        }
                       finaldata.Add(Data);
                     }
 var dresult = finaldata.GroupBy(x => x.Keys).Select(g => g.First()).ToDictionary(x => x.Values);
```

My finaldata is of type  `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`

Comment: What is `finaldata`,  what is `Keys`?

Comment: What do you want it to return?

Comment: i want to return the same List<Dictionary<string, object>> but without having duplicate ID

Comment: any reason for downvote?

Comment: you can use [Enumerable.Distinct<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, IEqualityComparer<TSource>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: in you case only `ID` key can be duplicated or any key in dictionary?

Comment: @Grundy Any key, but i want to filter by ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.Distinct Method (IEnumerable, IEqualityComparer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx)
for example if you want check "ID" key, you can use something like this

```
public class DictionaryEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<string,object>>
{

    public bool Equals(Dictionary<string, object> x, Dictionary<string, object> y)
    {
        object xid,yid;
        return x.TryGetValue("ID", out xid) 
            && y.TryGetValue("ID", out yid)
            && ((int)xid == (int)yid); //note: `int` only for example, use your type for "ID" key
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Dictionary<string, object> obj)
    {
        object xid;
        return obj.TryGetValue("ID", out xid) ? xid.GetHashCode() : obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
var dresult = finaldata.Distinct(new DictionaryEqualityComparer());
```